# how to use execlp to locate command in unix

Tags: unix, arguments, exec

In my program user will type the command and its arguments and I want to locate it. For example he prints wc -l -c. Since I don't know how many argument he will enter, how should I use execlp?
the syntax for execlp is 
 `int execlp(const char*file,const char *arg0...,(char*)0);`
Assume that I store command and its arguments in
  `char* arguments[]`.

Answer (score 0):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

You want execvp(). –  FatalError